# Adding multiple count in a group by query using codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My Table looks like this:

```
| id | employee_id |   status  |
   1      2           Present
   2      2           Present
   3      2           Absent
   4      2           Holiday
```

here is my query:

```
    $this->db->select('employee_id,COUNT(*) as num_present',FALSE);
    $this->db->group_by('employee_id'); 
    $this->db->group_by('status'); 
    $query  =  $this->db->get('xin_payroll_temp'); 
    $data = $query->result();

    print json_encode($data);
```

Output of the query:

```
  {
    "employee_id": "2",
    "num_present": "2"
  },
  {
    "employee_id": "2",
    "num_present": "1"
  },
  {
    "employee_id": "2",
    "num_present": "1"
  }
```

My query counts the `Present` , `Absent` , `Holiday`, but the problem is that it displays it in separate array data.

What i want is to display it in a single array with this format:

```
{
 "employee_id": "2",
 "num_present": "2",
 "num_absent" : "1",
 "num_holiday" : "1"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want that without loop or with loop?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Please refer this link for better idea. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Also can you please share the result of `$data` ( $data = $query->result();)

Comment: my goal is to query data from the database with the format above..i want to group the employee_id and count all the absents, presents and holidays..i know what loop is, i just want to know what query to use.. i already show what the output of my code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search on google i finally solved the problem.
Here is the query i used to achieve the format that i want:

```
        $query = $this->db->select('employee_id, sum(case when status = "Present" then 1 else 0 end ) As present_count, sum(case when status = "Absent" then 1 else 0 end ) As absent_count, sum(case when status = "Holiday" then 1 else 0 end ) As holiday_count',FALSE)
          ->from("xin_payroll_temp")
           ->group_by('employee_id')
           ->get();

    $data = $query->result();

    print json_encode($data);
```